# How to display an image as associated with a category on a category page?

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook

Let's say I have a link like this:

```
http://example.com/category/the-category-page
```

When I use that on Facebook I get the default image for the site. What I want is behavior that is like posting a link to a post where it shows the featured image. How can I get a featured image associated with a category and then have it show up on social media when I post a link to that category page?

Answer (score 0):

Search about "OpenGraph"

An example code for you:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://babality.com/img/babalityog.png"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="Babality - Oyunlar, Hileler, Combolar" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Babality - Oyunlar, Hileler, Combolar"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Babality.com; kaliteli ve eğlenceli oyunların, popüler oyunlara ait hilelerin ve comboların bulunduğu bir web sitesidir." />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://babality.com/" />
```

Write them between  .

Be sure your image has at least 200px width and 200px height. These rules given by Facebook so watch them closely.

After you insert your code, you can check (sign in required) from here:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the issue. As I stated already, when I post a link to a post like http://example.com/my-post-title I get the featured image, but for categories I do not even know how to make a featured image attach to a category. The question is "how can I get a featured image associated with a category"?

Comment: I saw "wordpress" tag in your question. So use this code for your category template? Also, don't forget about this! Somethimes even if you have correct values, Facebook sharer will bring old values. You can either wait for your cache to be removed or use debugger tool that I gave. If you want this codes to be automatically added to your category pages too, I suggest you contact your theme creator (if you did not created it) or compare your post template and category template to check if they both have same code for opengraph. I guess they don't. So try to add these codes to category template

Comment: I have confirmed that open graph works on all pages on the site in question. The problem is that Wordpress does not, by default, have a "featured image" for an entire category. Featured images work for posts and pages. The question is how to link a featured image to a category so that I can have different images show when linking to different category pages. I get why this functionality isn't default, but I am trying to figure out how to add it.

Comment: Allright than sorry I couldn't help to you. I've always thought it might be something related to category template.

Comment: It likely is, but I also think there needs to be a way to assign an image to the category itself. Thanks for trying